# GitHub API Patch make template not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, python-requests, github-api

I am using GitHub API to make my public repos to private and turn them into templates.
The repo permission is changing to private but they are not being modified to be templates. I can change them to templates from the GitHub UI.

The [GitHub repo patch guide](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#edit) says `is_template=true` should work.

Below is my code:

```
make_private = requests.patch(f"https://api.github.com/repos/{repo['owner']['login']}/{repo['name']}",
                              data=json.dumps({
                                              "private": True,
                                              "is_template": True
                                          }),
                              headers={'Authorization': 'token cefr9r2rrRandomRandomString',
                                       'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing the Accept header mentioned in those docs:

> **Note**: The `is_template` and `template_repository` keys are currently available for developer to preview. ... To access these new
>   response keys during the preview period, you must provide a custom
>   [media type](https://developer.github.com/v3/media) in the `Accept` header:
>
> ```
> application/vnd.github.baptiste-preview+json
> ```

Comment: My bad, didn't see the use of the header for updates also :D